# Como você gostaria que fosse feita a comunicação entre a comunidade e a Stack Exchange?

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

<sup>*Eu sei que o [nome da empresa voltou a ser Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/), mas ainda é bem comum chamá-la de Stack Exchange, ou simplesmente "SE". Eu optei por usar este nome na tradução para não confundir com o site Stack Overflow em inglês (SOen), e também por - na minha opinião - ser melhor do que chamá-la simplesmente de "a empresa".*</sup>

---

Uma das principais características de qualquer Stack Overflow internacional é o idioma que usamos para construir nossa base de conhecimento em programação. Acredito que todos concordam que falar no nosso idioma nativo não é apenas mais fácil, mas também mais divertido. Tudo funciona melhor, até o momento em que precisamos falar com os funcionários da SE, ou usuários de outros sites da rede.

Há dois casos muito importantes que temos que considerar, com relação à comunicação entre a empresa Stack Exchange e uma comunidade internacional (ou entre duas comunidades internacionais):

1. Quando um usuário de um site internacional quer compartilhar algo com a SE
2. Quando um funcionário da SE quer compartilhar algo com a comunidade internacional

No passado, esses dois tipos de comunicação eram feitos por um CM bilíngue que trabalhava com o site. Esta pessoa servia como uma ponte entre a SE e a comunidade: ele traduzia todas as postagens de um meta internacional para inglês, compartilhava as traduções com o restante do time, e por fim traduzia as respostas (assim como anúncios, discussões, etc) para o idioma alvo. Em algum ponto percebemos que esta abordagem não funcionava para nenhuma das partes envolvidas.

[A única abordagem que encontramos e que funcionava](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315311/274323), baseada nas nossas tentativas, foi quando:

1. Um usuário internacional postava no Meta Stack Exchange em inglês (ou postava no meta internacional em seu idioma nativo, e pedia a outros para postar no MSE em inglês).
2. Um funcionário postava em inglês em um meta internacional e pedia à comunidade que traduzisse para o respectivo idioma do site <sup>*como é o caso deste post*</sup>.

Quando pensamos no processo acima, nossos objetivos eram:

- *Acesso à qualquer funcionário da SE*. Queremos que as comunidades internacionais não dependam de uma única pessoa (um CM, um tradutor, ou qualquer outra). Precisa que algo seja corrigido? Eis aqui os desenvolvedores. Precisa de um ajuste no sistema, eis aqui um CM com permissões para fazê-lo! Não precisa esperar por ninguém.
- *Mais atenção aos problemas dos sites internacionais*. Cada site internacional sozinho pode não parecer tão grande. Ao mesmo tempo, todos os Stack Overflows internacionais juntos formam uma comunidade enorme, que eu acredito que em um futuro não muito distante não seja tão menor que a comunidade em inglês. Tudo que precisamos é trabalhar juntos.
- *Autossuficiência*. Parece que no passado víamos o CM como um tipo de líder. Por outro lado, os usuários é que são os verdadeiros líderes. Para que a mudança aconteça, precisamos querer dar aos usuários mais oportunidades de contribuir com o sucesso da comunidade (e traduções são parte desta ideia).

Recentemente [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) (o qual agradeço muito por isso!) e eu estivemos discutindo se há um jeito de melhorar esta comunicação, e concordamos que seria ótimo escutar ideias da comunidade!

> Como você gostaria de se comunicar com a SE? Como você gostaria que a SE se comunicasse com a comunidade? Você vê alguma forma de melhorar o processo atual?

Por favor compartilhem suas ideias!

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu acho que a maneira como funciona agora é a melhor (eu descrevi o post). Também fizemos muitos ajustes internos e, como vejo agora, a MSE é um ótimo lugar para conversar com a empresa. Não é?

Comment: É e não é. Para chegar no MSE é necessário uma demanda de recursos humanos enorme por parte da comunidade, tanto no quesito de identificar um problema, entender um problema, definir escopo do problema e pensar em soluções. Com a MSE essa demanda fica a cargo apenas da comunidade e a SE basicamente recebe o problema já estruturado e, geralmente, com uma proposta de solução. Por que toda essa demanda precisa ser apenas da comunidade? Sinto que a SE se ausenta muito justamente nos períodos de identificar um problema.

Comment: Para exemplificar isso, todos os posts no Meta por parte da SE são do tipo "hey, vamos resolver os problemas da comunidade? Que tal sugerirem soluções" e nunca um membro da SE se dispôs a participar efetivamente da comunidade e reconhecer esses problemas.

Comment: Relacionado: https://dearstackexchange.com/

Comment: @Maniero Olá! Como você está? =) A propósito, acho que esse link não está relacionado à questão.

Comment: Não é sobre a falta de comunicação da empresa com a comunidade?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Minha abordagem pessoal é ouvir, não falar. Os usuários geralmente têm idéias muito melhores do que eu =)

Comment: @Maniero Esta pergunta sobre precisamente como os funcionários compartilham suas idéias com o SOpt e como o SOpt pode compartilhar seus pensamentos. Esse link é sobre problemas diferentes, a meu ver.

Comment: Um problema constante na nossa comunidade: como incentivar os usuários a serem mais ativos no Meta? São pouquíssimos os que são ativos aqui.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Exatamente esse é o meu ponto. A SE é passiva, espera quieta até que a comunidade reclame. Para conseguir reclamar, a comunidade sozinha precisa reconhecer os problemas e analisá-los, determinar causa e levantar consequências. Como nossas ferramentas são limitadas, geralmente os danos que esses problemas causaram são irreversíveis ou no mínimo muito custoso para reverter. A comunidade não consegue identificar em tempo hábil os problemas e já pensar em soluções. É necessário que a SE seja proativa nesse sentido, tanto em auxiliar na identificação dos problemas como soluções.

Comment: Ouvem mais do que falam... e se ninguém fala, está tudo certo; enquanto na realidade a comunidade segue em caos sem saber o porquê.

Comment: Uma das coisas que mais se fala hoje em dia na rede toda é como os usuários dão ideias e elas nunca são aplicadas, ou como o staff ignora a comunidade de uns tempos para cá, por isso achei o link relacionado. Muito das pessoas não darem ideias mais é porque sabem que elas não serão aplicadas. Tem um monte de problema acontecendo e nada é feito há um bom tempo. As pessoas não querem mais ficar repetindo, acho que agora esperam que a SE comece olhar tudo o que já foi dito antes.

Comment: E para exemplificar isso é só olhar quantas perguntas aqui no Meta há a presença de alguém da SE. Quase nenhuma, o que demonstra o descaso em querer solucionar o problema, apenas querer a solução pronta (e muitas vezes ignorar por não reconhecer o problema).

Comment: O Meta já é uma área que a comunidade/staff tratam sobre a própria comunidade e resolve todos os problemas de comunicação. Funciona muito bem, por exemplo, entre os usuários que participam aqui. A comunicação com a SE falha porque ela não participa; e não participa porque não quer ficar traduzindo texto. Outro exemplo de "traduzam para inglês e venham até mim". Passiva de novo. Acredito que muito do que será discutido mostrará que não é a comunicação o problema, mas sim uma das partes da comunicação que não quer se comunicar. Será que vale a pena sugerir novas formas e a SE ignorá-las também?

Comment: Sobre a forma atual, confesso que sou relutante em postar no MSE. Não entendo um site meta com reputação separada, pois se pessoas suficientes discordarem de vc, sua reputação cai e vc não conseguirá nem votar nos outros posts (é como uma "punição" por dar uma ideia ruim). Isso só incentiva ideias que reforçam o *status quo*, é só ver que qq ideia nova é geralmente rechaçada por lá, ou esquecida. E isso passa uma impressão ruim, de que talvez seja exatamente isso que a SE quer: somente fingir que escuta as ideias, mas sem mudar nada de fato.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky é exatamente como diz o Anderson. Como a comunidade vai comunicar com quem raramente aparece por cá, e quando aparece é para meter uns textos em Inglês que nem se preocupa em traduzir. A comunidade que traduza se quiser. Se desse para ganhar dinheiro sem fazer nada ainda era melhor.

Comment: Eu ia responder que um bom ponto de partida é **tentar** - pelo menos uma vez para ver se funciona e se melhora em algo - postar em português, mas pensando bem, acho que esse é o menor dos problemas. O principal é o que já foi dito nos comentários e na resposta abaixo: os canais já existem, falta uma das partes (a SE) querer participar mais, ouvir a comunidade, etc. Se a postura da SE não mudar, tanto faz o idioma que usarem...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu entendo o que você disse. Sinto muito por isso. Ninguém queria que você se sentisse mal. Ao mesmo tempo, estou tentando ser proativo. Durante o último ano, sugeri algumas iniciativas que podemos implementar (na verdade, fizemos algumas!). Concordo que estas não estão relacionadas a mudanças no mecanismo, mas são para melhorar o ambiente em que todos nós dia após dia ajude nossos colegas. Também é importante.

Comment: Se não estiver faltando algo, atualmente o PM e os desenvolvedores estão fazendo uma varredura ativa no MSE em busca de bugs e solicitações de recursos. É por isso que peço que você publique no MSE o que você quiser ver no site. Todos os sites internacionais compartilham mais ou menos as mesmas necessidades.

Comment: A empresa se preocupa com os usuários. Sobre todos os usuários em geral. Como qualquer outra empresa no mundo, temos recursos limitados. Quando nossos PMs estão priorizando o que os desenvolvedores devem fazer, eles definitivamente consideram quantos usuários serão afetados. Até que um bug ou uma solicitação de recurso no MSE seja difícil dizer os números reais.

Comment: Eu entendo toda a sua frustração, é definitivamente o que eu sentiria se fosse você. Ao mesmo tempo, tendo em mente o que a empresa pode ou não fazer, estou tentando encontrar a melhor opção possível, que pode funcionar para todos, e eu adoraria ouvir suas idéias também.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Muitos dos problemas aqui na comunidade já foram amplamente discutidos aqui no Meta (alguns mais de uma vez, inclusive). Você já navegou pelo MSOpt para verificar esses tópicos e analisar o que vocês, SE, podem fazer a respeito? Seria interessante você responderem esses tópicos e participarem das discussões.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss É muito difícil para mim pesquisar no site, pois está em português. Eu apreciaria se você me desse os links que eu deveria olhar.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Bom, consegue perceber o gargalo da comunicação? O meta já existe para ser discutido sobre a comunidade. Isso é feito, sugestões e discussões aparecem toda semana. A SE se preocupa em ler e participar disso? Não.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Tem alguma previsão de quando vocês se posicionarão quanto às respostas presentes ou se omitiram novamente da discussão "porque vocês preferem só (fingir) ouvir"?

Answer (score 20):

> Como você gostaria de se comunicar com a SE?

A forma de comunicar existe, o meta, o chat, etc. O que a SE precisa mesmo é aparecer. Os canais não funcionam não é por serem bons ou fracos, é porque falta um dos interlocutores da Comunicação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Como você gostaria que a SE se comunicasse com a comunidade?

Que a SE participasse mais na comunidade. Para se ter a real noção dos problemas tem de se ter uma participação ativa na comunidade. Porque, como acontecia até há uns tempos atrás é que a SE nem sequer entendia os nossos problemas por mais que a comunidade tentasse resolver não havia feedback, ou pouco havia. Hoje em dia, quase parece que nem sequer tentam.

> Você vê alguma forma de melhorar o processo atual?

Não existe processo atualmente, a SE vai publicando aqui umas perguntas de vez em quando para mostrar que andam por ai, mas é só fogo de vista, basta ver o [Portuguese Language](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com) que nem a este tipo de interação tem direito.

Comment: só a ilustração já valia +1

Comment: Claro que a ideia que sugiro é meio "sem noção", mas talvez o SE poderia criar nichos de linguagens diferentes. Eles só querem aceitar perguntas em inglês, e talvez tenham uma demanda alta para todos os pedidos, então porque não ter um SEpt, SEru, SEes? Compor o time de pessoas que falam e entendem português justamente para abordar estes problemas. Ou eles mesmos poderiam resolver, ou se a SE ainda quisesse decidir sozinha, pelo menos os funcionários da SEpt poderiam traduzir para o inglês e então passar o problema para a SE,o problema seria mais prioritário e teriam que analisá-lo melhor.

Comment: @riki481 isso seria muito bom, mas duvido que a SE se desse a esse trabalho, parece que o número de funcionários (CM's) tem diminuído e não aumentado.

Answer (score 10):

Eu estou atuando no meta nos últimos dias. O que eu vejo é que a direção da SE está desconectada de suas comunidades. Isso levou a esse fiasco todo de renúncia em massa de moderadores e greve de muitos outros e instaurou esse clima de caça às bruxas por causa de algo que deveria ser um pequeno detalhe.

Ultimamente, a SE não tem falado muito com as suas comunidades e muito menos ouvido elas. Não há participação efetiva de ninguém da SE. Quando alguém aparece, é apenas para impôr novas regras para consertar algo que não está quebrado (a exemplo do [MCVE vs min-reprex](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/384994)).

A comunidade não confia mais na SE porque ela toma decisões unilaterais no mínimo questionáveis e [ridiculariza seus próprios usuários no twitter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335173/176034).

Sugestões e bugs são postadas no meta e solenemente ignoradas por anos. Dada essa situação, a ponte entre o meta e o SOpt acaba em grande parte até perdendo o sentido de ser usada, pois não produzirá frutos. Somando isso com a completa ausência da administração da SE aqui no SOpt, esta comunidade hoje cresce e vive quase que completamente isolada e desconectada da SE como um todo, sendo administrada exclusivamente pelos nossos moderadores. E dado o fato de que a SE anda fazendo coisas no mínimo questionáveis e duvidosas, infelizmente, esse isolamento pode até acabar sendo benéfico para o SOpt, sendo que idealmente deveríamos é estar nos aproveitando de uma interação harmoniosa com todo o resto do ecossistema da SE.

A principal reinvidicação atual aqui no SOpt é sobre as traduções. Eu particularmente detesto ver qualquer coisa na UI em inglês porque isso é algo desrespeito com o próprio fato de isso ser uma comunidade em português. Para você ter uma ideia, imagine que você estivesse trabalhando em um site que estivesse parte em inglês e parte em chinês, com diversos textos em chinês importantes que você não tem a menor ideia do que significam. Isso seria extremamente desconfortável pra você. É algo extremamente hostil para principiantes. No entanto, traduções estão sempre sendo revertidas de uma hora para outra sem nenhum aviso e o site nunca encontra-se totalmente traduzido.

Um outro problema que temos aqui é que a qualidade média das perguntas têm caído progressivamente nos últimos 2 anos mais ou menos. Hoje em dia é muito mais difícil achar perguntas boas para responder do que já foi um dia e isso também acaba tendo como efeito colateral a piora na recepção das perguntas feitas por usuários novos. Ninguém especificamente têm culpa nisso, afinal perguntas pessimamente elaboradas que não tem como ser respondidas não terão um bom destino independente de como sejam recebidas, logo a culpa não é da comunidade, e também não faz sentido jogar a culpa nos novatos. Entretanto, acho que isso é um problema que ocorre em todos ou quase todos os sites da SE, e a SE tem tomado apenas decisões cada vez mais confusas, erradas e lunáticas para tentar corrigir isso, frequentemente piorando o problema ou utilizando-se de bodes expiatórios cada vez mais malucos ao invés de atacar a real raiz do problema, que é dar melhores formas e orientações aos novatos para que postem perguntas melhores.

Há ainda outros problemas. Decisões tomadas pela SE acabam tendo algum tipo de efeito aqui no SOpt e devido ao isolamento desta comunidade, quase todos são pegos de surpresa. Isso inclui coisas como cláusula de arbitragem, CoC, alterações de licença, mudanças na UI, entre outros. Grande parte dessas mudanças são simplesmente desconhecidas da maioria dos usuários aqui e mesmo os poucos que já ouviram falar, não têm ideia do que realmente significam ou de como teriam qualquer efeito aqui.

Acho louvável que você tenha vindo até aqui para pedir sugestões. No entanto, esse é apenas o começo. É necessário conversar mais com os usuários e de forma ativa, ao menos uma vez por semana no meta, sem nunca deixar de ouvir e nem de dar feedback. Por sorte da SE e desta comunidade, até que nós no SOpt sabemos nos virar bem sozinhos, mas não é isso o que têm acontecido em diversas outras comunidades.

Comment: Me lembro da vez que fomos chamados de sociopatas cegos por um CM e a SE disse que ele falava por ela. Me lembro quando eles reconheceram que não estavam ouvindo a comunidade e nada mudou quase 2 anos depois, ou mudou, passaram ouvir menos ainda. E acho que isso é parte do motivo da comunidade perder a motivação. Sim, ela tem um pouco culpa do site não evoluir, mas só porque é dado o exemplo por parte da SE. Temos problemas sérios com a qualidade da participação da comunidade e dos novatos e nada é feito. Hoje pedir sugestões não tem valor mais, não acreditamos mais na SE.

Comment: A qualidade sempre caiu ano após ano, é que no começo ainda tinha muita coisa boa e disfarçava mais. Esse ano quase não tem nada bom e temo pelo próximo ano. Este ano passou ser quase que só "faça isso pra mim", "depure meu código" ou "me dê uma dica ou ajuda genérica qualquer só para mim". Estamos até deixando passar algumas coisas que normalmente seriam fechadas. Está deixando de ser divertido ser membro ativo do site, principalmente quando você toma ações que desagradam alguns sofre retaliações e fica por isso mesmo porque se você sozinho fizesse algo poderia ser considerado retaliação.

Comment: A culpa por isso é não ter melhores formas de recepcionar e ensinar os novatos como usar a plataforma ou mesmo como dar os primeiros passos antes de programar coisas complexas que ela não entende. Isso até poderia ser feito pelos usuários, mas pra que, se é sempre repetitivo e todo mundo já colabora muito com coisas mais importantes? A SE não tem conseguido sequer dar algum passo em relação a isto, mesmo que não resolvesse totalmente o problema. E olha que estamos aqui falando de novo e será ignorado.

Comment: Stafusa e entretanto o seu ultimo paragrafo não faz mais sentido, como sempre as perguntas aparecem aqui só para mostrar serviço e ninguém vem dar um feedback das nossas respostas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Esse era apenas o começo, mas não supreendentemente, ficou apenas nisso. Considerando o rumo que as coisas estão tomando na governança da SE, já perdi minhas esperanças quanto a qualquer melhoria no futuro. De agora em diante, é ladeira abaixo, o máximo que podemos é controlar a velocidade da queda.

Comment: @VictorStafusa vejo o "ladeira abaixo" da mesma forma, e tenho dito isto abertamente já faz um tempo. A maior dúvida pra mim é se prolongar o sofrimento (controlando a velocidade da queda) é bom ou ruim.